# Подскажите как грамотно сверстать блок

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Есть блок с услугами и ценами
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сверстать такой блок) Никак не могу придумать...

Comment: Выглядит как таблица, верстается как таблица.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Может есть более красивый способ, не знаю.

```css
  .row {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 400px;
    position: relative; }
    .row:after {
      content: '';
      display: block;
      width: 100%;
      height: 1px;
      left: 0;
      bottom: 4px;
      border-bottom: 1px dotted black;
      position: absolute;
      z-index: -1; }

.td {
  background: white;
  padding: 0 5px; }

  .td:nth-child(2) {
    margin-left: auto; }
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="td">Сантехника</div>
  <div class="td">300 гр</div>
</div>
```

Comment: а flex во всех браузерах работает?

Comment: от ie10+, ios 7 и т.д.

Comment: Благадарю)) очень выручили )

Comment: Префиксы не забудьте использовать.

Answer (score 2):

Сделайте заливку из точек, затем перекройте ее другой заливкой белого цвета:

```css
.info {
  background: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ZGVR.png") repeat-x left 68%;
  padding: 0;
}
.info>span {
  padding: 0 5px 0 0;
  background: #fff;
}
```

```html
<table width="100%">
  <tr>
    <td class=info>
      <span>Мозги кита</span>
    </td>
    <td>3000 P</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Не очень круто выглядит. На моем мониторе часть обрезанной "точечки" видна. Лучше всего будет это сверстать как таблицу из 2-х столбцов, последний - фиксированной ширины, а каждой первой ячейке в псевдоэлементе в поле 'контент' указать много точек, а `overflow` поставить хидден. Лень реализовывать,  к тому же вопросы "напишите код за меня" часто недолюбливают, странно.